# How can I do to Edit a record with losing the actual data of it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, edit

The error I'am receiving when I try to upload a File on a record already existed, is this:
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

```
public ActionResult Edit(Project mcs, HttpPostedFileBase file, [Bind(Include 
= "ProjectID,NumberMCP,EngineerID,SiteLocationID,nameProject,Ptype,Pyear, 
Fr, 
Fc, MCPcontent, Proj, ContentType")] Project project)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {

                            System.IO.File.Delete(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/"), mcs.Proj));

                         string ds = 
                         file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.Length - 3);
                         string p = string.Empty;
                         p = Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/");
                         file.SaveAs(p + file.FileName);


                            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
                            byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

                            using (db)
                            {
                                mcs.Proj = file.FileName;
                                mcs.ContentType = file.ContentType;
                                mcs.MCPcontent = buffer;
                                db.Projects.Add(mcs);   
                                db.SaveChanges();

                            }



                            ViewBag.EngineerID = new SelectList(db.Engineers, "EngineerID", "eName", project.EngineerID);
                            ViewBag.SiteLocationID = new SelectList(db.SiteLocations, "SiteLocationID", "nameSL", project.SiteLocationID);
                                return RedirectToAction("Index");
                            }
                        else
                        {
                            TempData["Message"] = "No se elegió ningún 
                             archivo.";
                            return RedirectToAction("Edit");

                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    return View();
                }
            }

            catch /*(Exception ex)*/
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Upload failed";
                return RedirectToAction("Edit");
            }

            }
```

I need some logic help in here please.

Comment: 404 means your form is submitting to an action method url which is not valid.

Comment: Post your view and what is the name of your controller?

Comment: @Waragi the name of nmy controller is Project. Gonna post the image in a while